# AWS IoT Core - attaching Things Attributes to payload

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot

So I have been playing around with AWS IoT Core. And I managed to create a few devices, run the examples and everything seems to work fine.

However, i encountered a strange situation that i cannot replicate:
All my devices have some Type w/ properly filled in Searchable attributes (and a few non-searchable attributes).
When one of my devices reports to a topic - its attributes are being appended into payload!!! 
But its not the case for other devices!!!

Does anyone know how to get a Thing to attach its attributes to payload in MQTT broker?

Comment: There's a few things that can be doing this, from IoT Rules, to it being put there by the device itself. Can you give us some more information about the topics, SDK and approach you're using?

Comment: can you share the code link?